# I am getting the error "jsonData is not defined at Object.<anonymous>" at line const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

Tags: node.js, json, express, backend, web-development-server

I am getting the error "jsonData is not defined at Object." at   line const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

This is the first time I am working with backend so any help would really be appreciated.
I am trying to create an application which sends newsletters to emails signed up for.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");            //importing express,body-parser,request,https
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");  //signup.html contains bootstrap loaded sign-in page for a form
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    const firstName = req.body.fName;   //form contains firstname,lastname and email id
    const lastName = req.body.lName;
    const email = req.body.email;

    var data = {
        members: [
            {
                email_address: email,
                status: "subscribed",
                merge_fields: {
                    FNAME: firstName,
                    LNAME: lastName
                }
            }
        ]
    };

const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);  //error line

const url = "https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/list_id";

const options = {
        method: "POST",
        auth: "anusha:api_key"
    }

    const request = https.request(url, options, function (response) {
        response.on("data", function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    })
});

request.write(jsonData);
request.end();

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's out of the scope, move it inside:

change this:

```
});

request.write(jsonData);
request.end();
```

to this:

```
    request.write(jsonData);
    request.end();
    
});
```